# Data Migration in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I weekly migrate table 'A' which has 4M data, after every 2-3 weeks I get the following error:

> [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'tableA_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tableA'. The duplicate key value is (13783250).".

While Source and Destination does not have any duplicate key.

**What is the reason behind this error?**

When I drop the table and start the migration again then data is loaded.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, and your database seems to think there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a non-trivial sized table and the PK violation is intermittent, my guess is that you are accessing the table using an isolation level that permits "dirty reads" or "phantom reads" while the source query is extracting data, a row "moves" and is then picked up "again" later on as the data is assembled.

If you up the isolation level to snapshot or read committed, I suspect *this* problem goes away but may introduce an issue with blocking during your ETL process.

Details of Isolation Level and the risks/rewards are covered in the Books Online article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql